Local Class field theory and Artin map for the Weil group
I am searching a reference for local class field theory that use the Weil group instead of the absolute Galois group. In particular that the Artin map is an isomorphism between the multiplicative group of a local field and the abelianization of the Weil group of this local field.
Are there some references in this direction?
